# Saving File without an extension

Tags: excel, vba

We have a system that creates files that are imported into Oracle. The files have the naming convention...

Filename.0000

Where the numbers are incremented with each export. So one file might be filename.4357 and the next file will be filename.4358.

I have managed to import the file into a spreadsheet as a comma delimited file where I then carry out some cleansing of the file.

I then want to save the file back to this unusual type .0000 but I can only seem to save it as Excel, CSV, TXT, PDF etc.

Does anyone have any ideas ? Thank you in advance.

Nothing yet

Comment: To start things off, you need to show us the code you are using to attempt this. Please see how to provide a [mre] and [ask]. Thank you!

Comment: "0000" is just the file extension - you can take any type of file and give it a ".0000" extension: what really matters is the underlying format of the file itself.  If your source files are plain-text then you need to figure out exactly how they're formatted and try to pick the appropriate selection from the existing list in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file as a txt file and close it. Then rename it in Windows Explorer.

You can also do that with VBA. Use the NAME command to rename it to a file name with the desired extension.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement